# jquery load() only works with alert()

Tags: jquery, ajax

the code below works only when i uncomment alert. What is the problem with this code.
**temp.html**

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="show"></div>
    <form id="chat_form">
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="abc"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#chat_form").submit(function (event) {
                $("#show").load("test.html", function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                    if (statusTxt == "success")
                        $("#abc").text(responseTxt);
                    if (statusTxt == "error")
                        $("#abc").text(xhr.statusText);
                    //alert( xhr.statusText);

                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

**test.html**

```
<p>hi i am test.html</p>
```

Comment: try to prevent the default form submit action - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/upfjLurm/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent the form to be get submitted:

```
$("#chat_form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // <-----add this to stop the form submission.
```

Comment: then how could the alert solve the problem because the alert is in a ajax callback.. so by the time the ajax request is completed the form should have got submited... unless it is a synchronous ajax request isn't it

Comment: @ArunPJohny i guess alert holds the screen at that point and OP is able to see the text in the div at that point of time, but when comment it out form just gets submitted and nothing is there in the div. i guess this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("#chat_form").submit(function (event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
 });
```